# How to configure an ALB to use Cognito auth generated by Amplify

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-application-load-balancer

I've got Cognito configured with social login for both Google and Apple from my app (configured using Amplify).

Because the Cognito auth uses a cookie, I can restrict access to an API Gateway using "AWS IAM". This works out of the box.

However, if I try set an ALB listener to use a Cognito app integration to authenticate requests it fails.

Has anyone been able to successfully do this or have any advice on setting up Cognito authentication via an app and restricting access using that auth on an ALB?